# CGContextDrawImage - EXC_BAD_ACCESS and MapOverlayRenderer

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have MapOverlayRenderer. Sometimes, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `CGContextDrawImage`

My image setter method to set overlay image

```
-(void)SetImageRef:(CGImageRef)imageRef
{       
    CGImageRelease(_imageReference);
    _imageReference = CGImageCreateCopy(imageRef);    
}
```

My draw method

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, self.interpolation);

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, _imageReference); //<---- EXC_BAD_ACCESS

}
```

What can be wrong, or how can I debug it.

If I enable Zombie Objects, crash dissappear, but no info is shown in debug console either, so I know nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you sometimes pass the *current* `_imageReference` to `SetImageRef:`.  Your implementation of `SetImageRef` does not safely handle this situation.  When you release `_imageReference` with `CGImageRelease` it will be deallocated (unless something else is retaining `_imageReference` but it sounds like that is not the case).  If you then make a copy with:

```
_imageReference = CGImageCreateCopy(imageRef);
```

and it just happens that `imageRef == _imageReference` then what happens?  You end up with `_imageReference` as a copy of a zombie (or soon to be zombie) image.  Now, you're making a copy, so you might think it doesn't matter if `imageRef` is dying (as long as it hasn't been overwritten immediately after the release, though this would still be unsafe code), but there's a catch.  The documentation for `CGImageCreateCopy` notes:

> Only the image structure itself is copied; the
>      underlying data is not.

So `_imageReference`'s "image structure" data might be safe, but the data that `_imageReference` will need to actually produce pixels is *not* safe.  And this is why you're seeing issues when you finally try to render the image with `CGContextDrawImage`.

This is all a very long winded way of saying you need to make `SetImageRef` a little more careful.  I suggest that you return early in the special case where `imageRef == _imageReference`:

```
-(void)SetImageRef:(CGImageRef)imageRef {
    if (imageRef == _imageReference) {
        return;
    }

    CGImageRelease(_imageReference);
    _imageReference = CGImageCreateCopy(imageRef);    
}
```

Comment: That was not the problem

Comment: Aaron, this solved my issue with the same error.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: @MartinPerry if that wasn't the issue, did you solve it another way? You should post it here if you did.

Answer (score 0):

I develop Color Picker for OS X and had same issue when i used two physical displays. Try write yours custom "setImageRef" as:

```
//Fix CGContextDrawImage Crash
-(void)SetImageRef:(CGImageRef)imgRef
{
    if (imgRef == _imageRef) return;
    CGImageRelease(_imageRef);
    _imageRef = CGImageCreateCopy(imgRef);
}
```

Aaron Golden has more detailed description for this issue.